# ArrayList generics

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

Could someone help me explain what `ma.add(new HighRights("AAA"));` does?

Main from class:

```
public static void main(String [] a){
            ArrayList<SecurityRights> ma=new ArrayList<SecurityRights>();
            ma.add(new HighRights("AAA"));
           }
```

HighRights class:

```
public class HighRights extends SecurityRights
{
    private String name;

    public HighRights(String n){
    super(true);
    this.name = n;
   }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }


    public static void main(String[] a){

    HighRights s= new HighRights("Lisa");
    System.out.print(s.getName() +" "+s.getSecret());                
  }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you don't understand. Can you pinpoint what part of the documentation is unclear?

Comment: This is about as self explanatory as it can get...

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E) ... it .. adds to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a simple Inheritance example.*

```
ma.add(new HighRights("AAA"));
```

It adds a new object of `HighRights` class into `List<SecurityRights>` array list `ma`.

```
HighRights extends SecurityRights
```

*This is inheritance.*
So its possible to store child object `HighRights` into parent object  `SecurityRights`.

Please read [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Answer (score 1):

It creates a new instance of `HighRights` class and adds it into an instance of `ArrayList<SecurityRights>`.

This is acceptable by the compiler since `HighRights` object instance pass the IS-A test ([`instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)) for the `SecurityRights` class bound.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<SecurityRights> ma=new ArrayList<SecurityRights>();
```

means that `ma` is an `ArrayList` of `SecurityRights`.

```
ma.add(new HighRights("AAA"));
```

means that you are creating a new object `HighRights`, initialized with the value `"AAA"`, and adding it to the `ma` array.

Since `HighRights extends SecurityRights`, Java will treat `HighRights` as `SecurityRights`.

Comment: How would i print out the values in HighRights?